# Blender takes a long time syncing objects in every frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I linked my source scene model to my animation scene and use a cube to drive this instance model.

When entering the rendering phase, Blender will spend a lot of time synchronizing the model. I spent 1 minute per frame in the synchronization model phase, and the rendering phase only took 10 seconds. I enabled Persistent Data, but it was of no use at all.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Persistant Data works for textures only**. It basically stores the images in the memory and uses it without loading it each time. There are not much details in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#final-render). So I don't really have a way to confirm what I said, but I had come to know about this from a [video on youtube](https://youtu.be/VEdd9CynwQU?t=444).

Currently there is no feature (within Blender) that allows to do the same thing with geometry. (There might be a custom solution by someone, but none in my knowledge.)